# error in \address and change error when i delete this

Tags: errors, header-footer

I create a Journal format, i have error in \address, but when i delete this, error change to next. please help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=40mm, bottom=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm,includehead=10mm,includefoot=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Sasa300}} \end{picture}}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\chead{VOL. 6, NO. 2, 1-20, 2018 \\\textbf{Academic Journal of Accounting and Economic Researches}\\ ISSN: 2333-0783 (Online)\\ ISSN: 2375-7493 (Print)}

\begin{document}
\title{Unncessarily Complicated Research Title}

\author{Mohammad Asadi}

\address{California, United States}

\begin{abstract}
Text of abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Science \sep Publication \sep Complicated



\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}



\subsection{Subsection One}




\subsection{Subsection Two}


\section{The Second Section}





\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{sample.bib}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this code provided by journal?

Comment: This might require `\maketitle`.  Also where is `keyword` defined?  (I didn't find it in `article`.)

Comment: I am the editor in chief of the Journal; I want to create LaTeX format for the articles.